# Regex substitute based on a condition

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently trying to do a simple regex substitution on a pandas dataframe df and below is my regex

```
df['data] = [re.sub(r'(\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10})+(;|:)+(\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10})','combo', str(x))
```

However I want this replacement to be done only if a certain row contains the term 'email' more than 2 times. Is there any efficient methods of doing this operation in python.

```
Input:

Row 1 : testdata1:testdata1 testdata2:testdata2 
Row 2 : testdata1:testdata1 testdata2:testdata2 email
Row 3 : email testdata1:testdata1 email testdata2:testdata2 email
```

Expected output:

```
Row 1 : testdata1:testdata1 testdata2:testdata2 
Row 2 : testdata1:testdata1 testdata2:testdata2 email
Row 3 : email combo email combo email
```

Comment: What's the logic in the replacement here?

Comment: Best method is likely to perform `"row".count("email")` and check if there are more than two instances. If so, run `re.sub` with the regex `[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10}[;:][a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10}`

Comment: I'm quite new to python so sorry if the below approach is wrong. I tried to do the following  

'
if df.data.str.count("Email") > 2:
    df['data'] = [re.sub(r'(https?:\/\/)?\w+(\.\w+)+(\/\w+)*(\/\w+\.\w+)?(\?[\w%&=.]*)*(?=[^\w.?&%=])','combo', str(x)) for x in df['data']]
else:
    pass
'
I'm getting an error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you need another regex pattern, something like

```
\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10}\s?[;:]+\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10}\b
```

The Pandas code can look like

```
df.loc[df['data'].str.count("email") > 2, 'data'] = df['data'].str.replace(r'\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10}\s?[;:]+\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10}\b','combo')
```

Or, to only count the word `email` as a whole word:

```
df.loc[df['data'].str.count(r"\bemail\b") > 2, 'data'] = df['data'].str.replace(r'\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10}\s?[;:]+\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10}\b','combo')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ByaLxx/1). Details:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10}` - five to ten alphanumeric chars
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `[;:]+` - 1+ semi-colons or colons
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10}\b` - five to ten alphanumeric chars and a word boundary.

With `df['data'].str.count(r"\bemail\b") > 2`, a "mask" is created, only those rows will be affected where there are more than two occurrence of `email` word.

Pandas test:

```
>>> df.loc[df['data'].str.count("email") > 2, 'data'] = df['data'].str.replace(r'\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10}\s?[;:]+\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10}\b','combo')
>>> df
                                            data
0        testdata1:testdata1 testdata2:testdata2
1  testdata1:testdata1 testdata2:testdata2 email
2                  email combo email combo email
```

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. This was something I was expecting